# analyzing the crash dump with __except

Tags: c++, c, winapi, windbg, crash-dumps

Suppose I have the following code

```
main()
{

   __try 
  {

   //---> SEH EXCEPTION HAS HAPPENED HERE

  }
   __finally
  {

   //---> CRASH DUMP WAS TAKEN HERE

  }

}
```

The crash dump was taken at the "--->" marked place. Can I know from userdump what was the original exception that brought us there. I cannot find any info in stack trace (seems just like normal execution without exception handler)

UPD: Sorry guys seems like the exception wasn't in the this thread, otherwise finally handler would be clearly called from __except_handler during the unwind phase. Need to close

Comment: Are you checking all threads?

Comment: It cannot be normal if there's an exception. What are the faulting instruction and the exception code? Most likely it's a bad pointer/array index or memory corruption that caused it.

Answer (score 1):

Use WinDbg and follow the details on this blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slavao/archive/2005/01/30/363428.aspx WinDbg can be downloaded from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463009

Answer (score 1):

You are just doing it wrong.  The crash dump should be made in the __except filter.  Now .excr and !analyze will work just fine in the debugger.